# Print first element of a string array which occurs one time

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have an array with names and I need to print out the first name which only occurs once. For example, I have the following names:

Joe, Andy, Albert, Andy, Tyler, Albert.

The program Should print out Joe (if there is no correct answer, then print out an empty line), because that is the first one which occurs once.

Here is my program so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int size;
cin >> size;
string trash;

string arr[size];

for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
}

getline(cin,trash);

string first;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
   if ( arr[i] != arr[i+1] )
    first = arr[i];
}

cout << first << endl;
}
```

Comment: Variables length arrays are not standard C++. That's your 1st problem. If I were to grade this, I'd fail it for this reason, full stop. The 2nd problem is that, of course, the search logic is completely broken. The logic consists of a loop that always compares one element to the next one. Therefore, the array is "Bob, Alice, Bob", this will fail miserably, because the two Bobs never compare. The comparison is always between adjacent elements which, of course, is completely wrong. You need to rethink, and write down, in short sentences, the correct algorithm first. Then translate it to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int size;
cin >> size;
// string trash;
string arr[size];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
}
// getline(cin,trash);
string first;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    first = arr[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
        if ( arr[i] == arr[j] && i!=j)
            first = "";
    }
    if (first == arr[i])
        break;
}

cout << first << endl;
}
```

Comment: In for loop with **j variable** in **if-statement**: add `break;` after `first = "";`. No need to continue if the same name has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Well with c++ stl you can make your life much easier,let me know if you don't understand any part.

below is implementatin

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<string>a(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];

    unordered_map<string,int>mapping; // to store the freqency of each unique string
                                      //actually we are intending to map each unique string to its frequency

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        mapping[a[i]]+=1; //incrementing the frequency of same string 
    }
    bool success=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(mapping[a[i]]==1) //if first time we get a string whose frequency is 1 we print it and break out of the loop
            {
                cout<<a[i]<<"\n";
                success=1;
                break;
            }
    }
    if(success==0)
       cout<<"\n";


return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this thoroughly, but I'd go for an approach like this. The min_element algorithm plays nicely:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> testNames;

int main()
{
    testNames.push_back("Joe");
    testNames.push_back("Andy");
    testNames.push_back("Albert");
    testNames.push_back("Andy");
    testNames.push_back("Tyler");
    testNames.push_back("Albert");
    map<string, vector<int>> nameHits;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != testNames.size(); ++i)
        nameHits[testNames.at(i)].push_back(i);

    map<string, vector<int>>::const_iterator cIter;
    cIter = min_element(nameHits.cbegin(), nameHits.cend(), 
        [](const pair<string, vector<int>>& e1, const pair<string, vector<int>>& e2)
        { return e1.second.size() == 1 && e1.second.at(0) < e2.second.at(0); });

    if (cIter->second.size() != 1 || cIter == nameHits.end())
        cout << "";
    else
        cout << (*cIter).first;

    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The point is the difference between the concept of stack and heap.

For a dynamic sized array try `std::vector`,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    string trash;

    vector<string> arr;
    arr.assign(size,"");

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    getline(cin,trash);

    string first;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if ( arr[i] != arr[i+1] )
            first = arr[i];
    }

    cout << first << endl;
}
```